# Share an ItemTemplate among Repeaters with different Header/Footer Templates

Tags: asp.net, webforms, repeater

We have a bunch of repeaters with different HeaderTemplates and FooterTemplates. The ItemTemplate is the same for all of them, though. How can we share the ItemTemplate among a bunch of Repeaters?

```
<asp:Repeater>
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <ul>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li><%# Eval("title") %></li>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </ul>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>

<asp:Repeater>
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <ol>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li><%# Eval("title") %></li>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </ol>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>

<asp:Repeater>
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <p>This is some intro text.</p>
        <ul>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li><%# Eval("title") %></li>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </ul>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: I suppose that the datasources of every repeater are different from one another?

Comment: Maybe you could define a unique OnItemDataBound event, and asing it to all those Repeaters, and prepare the contents of ItemTemplate from there.

Comment: @zed Yes. They all have different data sources.

Answer (score 0):

Related to may comment, I suggest to try the following: define a unique OnItemDataBound event, and asing it to all those Repeaters. This way you have the generation of the item in one place, at code behind.

For example, in your aspx:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" id="repeaterA" OnItemDataBound="CommonItemDataBound">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <ul>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="HtmlContents"></asp:Literal>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </ul>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>

<asp:Repeater runat="server" id="repeaterB" OnItemDataBound="CommonItemDataBound">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <ol>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="HtmlContents"></asp:Literal>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </ol>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

And then, in your code behind:

```
    protected void CommonItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        ((Literal)e.Item.FindControl("HtmlContents")).Text = string.Format("<li>{0}</li>", DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "title").ToString())
    }
}
```

Comment: The approach, then, is to create the ItemTemplate programmatically instead of in markup. That makes sense. Then I can share it among the repeaters.

Comment: Exactly. In the sample provided I show how to render plain html. If you need to have asp.net controls inside that ItemTemplate you could use an `<asp:Panel`instead of the Literal control.

Answer (score 0):

I think you showed just one element in `Itemtemplate` from an example prospective and in actual probably you have more elements to share. When it comes to Resuable controls in ASP.NET, one thing comes to my mind and that is `UserControls`, So you can do it by creating one like this:-

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="RepeaterUC.ascx.cs" 
           Inherits="Demo.RepeaterUserControl" %>
<li><%# Eval("title") %></li>
```

Finally register it in your page and use it:-

```
<%@ Register TagName="Fruits" TagPrefix="RC" Src="~/RepeaterUserControl.ascx" %>
 <ItemTemplate>
      <RC:Fruits runat="server"></RC:Fruits>
 </ItemTemplate>
 ...........and so on for other controls.
```

Comment: This is a useful approach. In this case, I may suggest that the entire `Repeater` should be placed inside the user control, and provide the contents of `HeaderTemplate` and `FooterTemplate` from outside the user control, every time you make use of it.

Comment: @zed - Yup Good point! But that all depends on OP's requirement and he can manipulate it accordingly.